# Unable to post values from a dynamic row containing a multiselect list box

Tags: php, javascript

I am able to dynamically create a multiple list box but I cannot post the values. The select element is a 2 dimensional array and I am not getting any values returned from the options.

Here is my javascript code:

```
function createSelectCell(cell,column,multiselect_type_flag)
{
var copyListBox = document.getElementById(column);
var newListBox = document.createElement('select');

if(multiselect_type_flag == 'F')
{
    newListBox.name = 'column_array_'+column+'[]';
}
else if(multiselect_type_flag == 'T')
{
    newListBox.name = 'column_array_'+column+'[][]';
    newListBox.size = '4';
    newListBox.setAttribute('multiple', 'multiple');
}

for (var i = 0; i < copyListBox.options.length; i++)
{
    var newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.text = copyListBox.options[i].text;
    newOption.value = copyListBox.options[i].value;
    newListBox.appendChild(newOption);
}
cell.appendChild(newListBox);
}
```

Requested for html in comments:

```
echo "<td><select id='".$column."' name='column_array_".$column."[$i][]' multiple='multiple' size='4'>";
```

When I do `print_r($_POST['column_array_'.$column]);` I get:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Secondary Contact ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Authorised to log calls ) )
```

when I should be getting:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Secondary Contact [1] => Authorised to log calls ) )
```

Comment: please, show your column html markup

Comment: echo "<td><select id='".$column."' name='column_array_".$column."[$i][]' multiple='multiple' size='4'>";

Comment: If I do a print_r on the post I receive this result:  print_r($_POST['column_array_'.$column]); Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Secondary Contact ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Authorised to log calls ) )  when I should be getting: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Secondary Contact [1] => Authorised to log calls ) )

Comment: I have added to my code: </br> `var arrayIndex = rowCount - 1;` and given the array an index: </br> `newListBox.name = 'column_array_'+column+'['+arrayIndex +'][]';` </br> although the problem now that I have is if I remove a row the index is overwritting one that is being used

Comment: `$post_column_array = array_values($_POST['column_array_'.$column]);` </br> This reset the array index so that after removing a row I was still able to loop through the array

Answer (score 0):

I have added the following to my code:

```
var arrayIndex = rowCount - 1;
```

and have given the array an index:

```
newListBox.name = 'column_array_'+column+'['+arrayIndex +'][]';
```

Answer (score 0):

this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Secondary Contact ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Authorised to log calls ) )
```

happens because you named your select with  [][], use instead single brackets and appropriate parent index e.g.:

```
<select name="column_array['columnA'][]"> ...o2,o3... </select>
<select name="column_array['columnB'][]"> ...o1,o4... </select>
```

so the result would be:

```
print_r($_POST['column_array'])

Array
(
 [columnA] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
        )
 [columnB] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 4
        )
)
```